# Can WebDriverBackedSelenium be used in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Does the Selenium 2 C# library support using Selenium 1 commands? In java you can create a WebDriverBackedSelenium object and use Selenium 1 commands but can this be done in C# ?

If yes, whats the syntax ?

Thanks,

Hasan

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty much the same as the Java Code. See below

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
ISelenium selenium = new WebdriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.google.com");
selenium.open("/");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AutomatedTester. have you tried using it yet? I am using webdriver 2.0b3 and get this error "System.NotSupportedException : open". Has the functionality of webdriverBackedSelenium been implemented for .Net ?

Comment: In the .NET bindings, you must call selenium.Start() before calling selenium.Open().

Comment: guys, is there a way to debug a webdriver test in visual studio?  I am using NUnit.